# Why we should not change content of returned value from TextView#getText()?

Tags: android, textview, android-editable

[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getText()) in about `TextView.getText()` say:

> Note: The content of the return value **should not** be modified. If you want a modifiable one, you should make your own copy first.

Also `TextView` has `setText (CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)` method and you can pass `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` to it to enable casting result of `getText()` method to an `Editable`. As [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable) say the purpose of `Editable` interface is:

> This is the interface for text whose **content** and markup **can be changed** [...]

My question is: If we can pass `Editable` to the `TextView` and get it, why we should not modify it?